# TimeZone and Working Hours for Users through EWS

Tags: timezone, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Is it possible to get TimeZone and working hours of the users through EWS?

I am able to extract TZ and Working Hours for current user(Account with which the ExchangeService is initialized)

```
UserConfiguration usrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "WorkHours", WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, UserConfigurationProperties.All);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(new MemoryStream(usrConfig.XmlData));
XmlNodeList nlList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("WorkHoursVersion1");
Console.WriteLine(nlList.Item(0).InnerXml);
string str = nlList.Item(0).InnerXml;
```

But I am not able to extract the same information for other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the [GetUserAvailability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) operation.

Input is an array of users. Output includes an [array of AttendeeAvailability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.getuseravailabilityresults.attendeesavailability%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), which contains a [WorkingHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.workinghours%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property, which itself includes TimeZone:

```
GetUserAvailabilityResults uars = service.GetUserAvailability(
    new AttendeeInfo[] { new AttendeeInfo(smtpAddressOfUser, MeetingAttendeeType.Required, true), ... }, 
    new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)), 
    AvailabilityData.FreeBusy
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the other mailbox in question all you need to do is use the FolderId class specify the Mailbox you want to access and then use the FolderId overload of the UserConfiguration.Bind method eg

```
        FolderId CalendarFolderId = new FolderId(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com");
        UserConfiguration usrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "WorkHours", CalendarFolderId, UserConfigurationProperties.All);
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: When I do this, I get this error {"The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."}

Comment: That error would indicate your not using the Primary SMTP for the Mailbox. Can you do a resolvename wit the same SMTP address eg
            NameResolutionCollection nc = service.ResolveName("user@domain.onmicrosoft.com", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);
            FolderId CalendarFolderId = new Data.FolderId(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, nc[0].Mailbox.Address);
            UserConfiguration usrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "WorkHours", CalendarFolderId, UserConfigurationProperties.All);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Exchange Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877053%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

You can have a specific user account impersonate another user account and access their details without the need for their username and password.

```cs
string impName = @"impy";
string impPassword = @"password";
string impDomain = @"domain";
string impEmail = @"impy@domain.com";

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(impName, impPassword, impDomain);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(impEmail);

service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, @"user@domain.com");
```

You should then be able to use `UserConfiguration.Bind()` to do what you are after.

More references:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)