# Getting Exchange Server's users timezone

Tags: outlook, timezone, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm having a bit of a problem. I am working on a small outlook plugin(in c#) with the following functions(very simplified):

Get all of the users from Exchange Server with their Timezone and add that info to the mailbody.

Getting all of the users isn't much of a problem but I have no idea about getting their Timezone.

outlook and exchange server sersion - 2010

Is there a way to achieve this?
Please advise.

Comment: The user can set that via OWA, you can read that via powershell. BUT if they use Outlook its a local OS value which you need to collect from there. So not sure what you expect go get here from the Exchange server.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.

I'm not sure I've I made my question clear.

I need my OWA plugin to get the server's users timezone.

I know this achievable via powershell, but is there anyway to do this from an outlook client?

Comment: i.e.
userOne - ETS
UserTwo - PTS
etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using getuseravailability which if it works would be the most effiencent way for a lot of users see [TimeZone and Working Hours for Users through EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478039/timezone-and-working-hours-for-users-through-ews) . Or try something like this http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2015/11/finding-timezone-being-used-in-mailbox.html

Answer (score 1):

User's TZ and workdays are stored as a hidden message in the Calendar folder - you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - go to the Calendar folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, double click on the row with `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.Configuration.WorkHours"`, look at the `PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM` stream property in the IMessage window (click on the "..." button next to the Value edit box).

I don't think you'd be able to retrieve hidden item from a shared folder belonging to a different user using the Outlook Object Model. You can try to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or EWS. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, it explicitly exposes [RDOExchangeMailbox.CalendarOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocalendaroptions.htm) property.